# SQLAlchemy pool recycle based on idle time instead of total time

Tags: sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy connection pooling offers a [recycle option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#setting-pool-recycle) which (if I'm reading the docs right) will invalidate connections after they have reached a certain total age.

MySQL has a config option [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) which closes connections after an idle period.

Is there a way to make the SQLAlchemy recycle work on the time since a connection was last actively used rather than its total age so that it lines up better with the server's behaviour?